# 64bit Thread Overhead

Tags: 64-bit, stack

What's the overhead of a thread on 64bit windows?  I believe it was 1mb of userspace for the stack and a smaller amount of kernel space in 32bit.

Thanks

Comment: Ferruccio's answer is correct, but even if it is set to 1MB. That 1MB isn't allocated immediately. It will get allocated on an as needed basis as your stack gets used.

Comment: To clarify: the address space is allocated immediately, but physical RAM will not be mapped to that address space until necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be whatever you want. The [CreateThread(](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453(VS.85).aspx)) API lets you specify stack size. If you call it with a stack size of 0, it will use the stack defined in the executable file header, which can be set via a linker option. The default value (for both x86 & x64 systems) is 1MB.